# Table Encryption file-per-table tablespace not encrypting

Tags: mysql, encryption

I have a BBDD (MySQL 8) with several tables. In one of them I have a blob column (called sensitive_data) which has more or less legible content if we perform a SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM sensitive_information WHERE sensitive_data LIKE '%name%';
```

This returns something like

????/namenKZ???Oj?B         | ?!John Doe???????????????

I installed keyring plugin and it's active:

```
PLUGIN_NAME  | PLUGIN_STATUS |
+--------------+-----------+ |
 keyring_file | ACTIVE
```

If I execute the statement:

```
ALTER TABLE sensitive_information ENCRYPTION='Y';
```

The output console says:

```
Query OK, 36 rows affected (0,01 sec)
Records: 36  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

But if I perform the same SELECT query I mentioned above I get the very same result, like no encryption was done.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So.. you assumed that if you enabled data-at-rest encryption that your columns will be *returned encrypted*? Now that you know you assumed wrong, there are 2 questions that pose themselves - **WHY** did you think so and **HOW** did you expect to deal with encrypted data? You'd get encrypted blob back, but how would you ever decrypt it? From what you wrote, you're not looking for data-at-rest encryption but in-app handled encryption where data is sent encrypted in-flight.

Comment: Hi N.B and thanks for your answer. I thought that encryption would encrypt the data in the data base just same way an encrypted data is sent and stored (e.g, a hashed password you sent from an application and it gets recorded the same way). I didn't see the point on encrypt data that gets decrypted when you perform a simple SELECT. But, as you pointed, nothing could be done if it would return an encrypted value, no data process could be done. So I guess that data-at-rest encryption does not protect data from being "readable". Thanks and regards.